# How do I make vim not beep when autoinserting new lines?

Tags: vim

Whenever I'm typing something like `function(){|}` (cursor is at '|') and hit ENTER, vim automatically drops me to the next line and autoindents, but it always beeps at me. Why does it beep and how can I make it not beep.

Note: I don't want disable beeping entirely, just wondering why it beeps in this particular case.

Comment: Do you know what plugin provides that functionality?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's auto-pairs.

Comment: Also, this only seems to happen when it would need to scroll the screen down. If i'm at the top of the file and there's plenty of room to display everything, it doesn't beep.

Comment: My best guess is that it has to do with the `'showmatch'` option, which issues a beep if a closing bracket/parenthesis is used without a matching opening bracket. For various reasons, some plugins that auto-insert this kind of thing insert the closing bracket first, then adds the opening bracket.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior when typing at the bottom of a window, even with `noshowmatch`. I also notice that it annoyingly requires two presses of `Esc` to exit insert mode.

Comment: I've also noticed occasionally having to `Esc` twice as well

Comment: It seems to have something to do with auto-pairs's autocentering behavior. I can't see why, though, since if I send the key sequences myself that it looks like the plugin sends, I don't notice any ill effects. For now, you can `let g:AutoPairsCenterLine = 0` to stop autocentering, as a workaround.